# How to calculate the integral on surface which cannot be expressed in functions easily?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Surface $S$ is part of $x^2+y^2=1$ between planes $z=0$ and $x+y+z=2$, a vector field $\vec{F}=x\vec{i}+y\vec{j}+z\vec{k}$, what is the value of integration $$ \iint_{S} \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n} dS$$

My solution is:
$$ \iint_{S} \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n} dS = \iint_{S} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S} = \iint_{S} xdydz + ydzdx + zdxdy$$
then I met a problem that I cannot express the surface $S$. I know it is a part of cylindrical surface between the plane $z=0$ and the intersection line of cylinder and the plane.

Could anyone please help me to work it out?

**Update:**

Thanks to James S. Cook, I get to know how to transform the surface integral into a double integral. So is the solution below right? If it is wrong, could anyone please point the mistakes out?

let $x=\cos{\theta}, y=\sin{\theta}$, so by changing the variable, we have the new integration area $X=\{(z,\theta): 0\leq z \leq 2-\cos{\theta} - \sin{\theta}, 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\}$, and the integral becomes:
$$\iint_{S} xdydz + ydzdx + zdxdy = \iint_{S} \left[\cos{\theta}(-\cos{\theta})+\sin{\theta}(-\sin{\theta})\right]dzd\theta 
=\int^{2\pi}_0 d\theta\int^{2-\cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta}}_0dz
=4\pi$$

Comment: I think the calculation's ok now, however, this only accounts for the flux of the vector field through the cut-cylinder. If they intended the closed surface we still need to add the flux of the base ($z=0$) and cap ($z=2-x-y$). I think the flux through the base is zero since the normal component of the vector field is zero for the base. I'm not sure about the cap without calculation. Is $4\pi$ not the expected answer?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook, according to the problem, it seems that we just need to calculate the flux through $S$. Nevertheless, there is one thing puzzles me that why the normal vector is $(\sin\theta, \cos\theta, 0)$. In fact, I do not have an expected answer for this problem.

Comment: Once you have a parametrization of a surface, say $X(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$ then we calculate partial velocities $\frac{\partial X}{\partial u} = X_u$ and $\frac{\partial X}{\partial v} = X_v$. Of course, these are tangent to the coordinate curves $X(u,v_o)$ and $X(u_o,v)$ through $p = X(u_o,v_o)$. We have $N=X_u \times X_v$ is perpendicular to both $X_u$ and $X_v$ hence it must point in the normal direction to the surface. The $\langle \sin \theta, \cos \theta, 0 \rangle$ can be calculate as I indicate in the answer $N = X_{\theta} \times X_z$. It's a short calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x+y+z=2$ then $z = 2-x-y$ you have $0 \leq z \leq 2 - x - y$ for the surface. I think it is natural to use $z$ and $\theta$ as parameters for the surface:
$$ X(\theta,z) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, z)$$
it is simple to calculate $X_{\theta} \times X_z = \langle \sin \theta, \cos \theta, 0 \rangle$. I usually denote this normal vector field as $\hat{r}$ as it is a unit-vector field which points in radial direction. So, you just need to calculate:
$$ \iint \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iint_D \vec{F}(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, z) \cdot \langle \sin \theta, \cos \theta, 0 \rangle \, dz \, d\theta $$
But, the parameter space $D$ is a bit complicated, $0 \leq z \leq 2 - x - y$ translates into:
$$ 0 \leq z \leq 2 - \cos \theta - \sin \theta $$
and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.
which suggests we should do the iterated integration with $dz$ as the first integral.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Now I understand the integral area, but I always have trouble finding the right normal vector for the surface. So I choose differential form method. However, it seems different from the answer derived from the normal vector method. Could you please help me figure the problem out? I have adding my calculation in the **update** in the problem description.